# Selenium in "HeadLess" mode "Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context'" on Vagrant

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, debian, vagrant

I try this simple code using selenium in "headless" mode:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import sys,os

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    current_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    chromeOptions = Options()
    chromeOptions.headless = True

    print('>>> [main] execute the driver')
    os_path_driver = "linux"
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=current_path + "/drivers/" + os_path_driver + "/chromedriver", options=chromeOptions)

    browser.get("http://linuxhint.com")
    print("Title: %s" % browser.title)

    browser.quit()
```

- On Windows, it's working.
- With my Vagrant VM, it's running Chrome browser (I'm in Headless mode !!) in the host machine (Windows), and this is the error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_selenium_headless.py", line 71, in <module>
    browser.get("http://linuxhint.com")
  File "/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 333, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context': {"auxData":{"frameId":"20671.1","isDefault":true},"id":1,"name":"","origin":"://"}
  (Session info: chrome=57.0.2987.98)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248304,platform=Linux 3.16.0-11-amd64 x86_64)
```

I've downloaded the last version (2.9) of ChromeDriver.

And, on a Debian server, same code, another error :

```
>>> [main] execute the driver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_selenium_headless.py", line 64, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=current_path + "/drivers/linux/chromedriver", options=chromeOptions)
  File "/home/users/XXX/YYY/env3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/home/users/XXX/YYY/env3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 98, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "/home/users/XXX/YYY/env3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 111, in assert_process_still_running
    % (self.path, return_code)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /home/users/XXX/scripts/drivers/linux/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -11
```

The driver's path in the $PATH.

Can you help me please ?

Thanks a lot :)

F.